# How do you sort month name by alphabetical C# ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

Currently, my output is

`Mar, Jan, Feb`.

But I want it to be `Jan, Feb, Mar`

This is my code, can anyone help me get sorted month output.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct Count(Feedback_id) as CountFeedback, CONVERT(varchar(3), visit_date, 100) as Month " +
                    "FROM Patient_Feedback " +
                    "WHERE YEAR(visit_date) = " + drpValue + " and feedback_type = 'appeal' " +
                    "Group by CONVERT(varchar(3), visit_date, 100) " +
                    "ORDER BY Month desc", con);
                Series series = Chart2.Series["Series2"];
                Chart2.ChartAreas["ChartArea2"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    series.Points.AddXY(rdr["Month"].ToString(), rdr["CountFeedback"].ToString());
                }
                string impPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + tmpChartName;
                Chart2.SaveImage(impPath);
            }
```

Comment: There is an error though.. Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
CONVERT(varchar(3), visit_date, 100) as Month
```

With

```
DATEPART(m, visit_date) as Month
```

Your query should look like this (I didn't try to compile it)

```
Select distinct Count(Feedback_id) as CountFeedback, CONVERT(varchar(3), visit_date, 100) as Month, DATEPART(m, visit_date) MonthNumber
FROM Patient_Feedback
WHERE YEAR(visit_date) = drpValue and feedback_type = 'appeal'
Group by CONVERT(varchar(3), visit_date, 100), DATEPART(m, visit_date)
ORDER BY DATEPART(m, visit_date)
```

Comment: There's an error though... Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: Just put DATEPART(m, visit_date) in the select. I already update the answer.

Comment: Hi Rawitas Krungkaew, i want it to be 'Jan' and not '1'

Comment: There are two fields, one with 1 and another with Jan, if you just look closely into my query.

Comment: My bad... I over looked it... but it still display as Feb, Jan

Comment: That's my bad, it should order by ascending order

Comment: Perhaps, do you know how to solve this error? When i run that SQL this error pop out System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.'

Comment: updaed my answer few minutes ago

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort date in ascending order, why not simply order by date asc, like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct Count(Feedback_id) as CountFeedback, CONVERT(varchar(3), visit_date, 100) as Month " +
            "FROM Patient_Feedback " +
            "WHERE YEAR(visit_date) = " + drpValue + " and feedback_type = 'appeal' " +
            "Group by CONVERT(varchar(3), visit_date, 100), visit_date " +
            "ORDER BY visit_date ASC", con);
```

Comment: There's an error though.. Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Column "Patient_Feedback.visit_date" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: well, I update my answer. The reason is that visit_date isn't in GROUP BY clause.